# Clustering and replication among nodes in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish-3, cluster-computing

I configured my Glassfish server to single machine clustering. After deploying my website into it, web browser is not getting data from the server.

Am I missing anything? Can I replicate the data using this clustered nodes? What are the prerequisites other than GlassFlish server to solve my problem (Clustering and Replication)?

Comment: Are you getting an error in the web browser?

Comment: It is very difficult to get help with this problem unless you provide some detail.  What is the error message?  What have you tried to fix it?  Have you seen anything in the logs that might help figure out what's wrong?